# how to send data from express server to mongodb database in kubernetes using service name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, kubernetes

all my pods are running and i am testing both server, client and database using mongodb atlas, the app works but when i change to use mongodb pod, I have 4000 (bad server request)

mongodb works fine, I test it with mongosh ' kubectl exec -it  //bin//sh
mongo -u user -p password
show database (works)

> show dbs
> admin   0.000GB
> config  0.000GB
> local   0.000GB
> test    0.000GB
> db.test.find()
> { "_id" : ObjectId("62fb942345a2c5286fc7455f"), "todo" : "first element in this database" }

//controller server js before i pushed to docker hub

```
const Todo = require('./models')

const add = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {todo} = req.body
        const new_todo = await Todo.insertOne({todo:todo})
        return res.status(200) 

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400)
    }
}
const all = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const todo = await Todo.find()
        return res.status(200).json({ todo })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(404)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    add,
    all
}
```

//****************************************************
mongodb service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

/*************************************

I'm not sure of a single thing, url that express will use to connect to mongodb with ClustrIP

"mongodb://mongodb-service:27017"

/*************************************

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT
const url = process.env.URL || 'mongodb+srv://najib:123@cluster0.z8y8j9v.mongodb.net/microTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority' // this is for test with mongodb atlas ans is working just fine , but when over it with this ["mongodb://mongodb-service:27017"] dont work 
const myRoutes = require('./routes')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose
    .connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() =>{
        console.log("MongoDB successfully connected")
        app.use('/', myRoutes)
    } )
    .catch(err => console.log(err))


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at port  ${port}`)
})
```

mongodb deployment

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pv
  labels:
    app: mongo-db
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /data/pv/wp-html
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata: 
  name: mongodb-pvc
  labels: 
    app: mongo-db
spec: 
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources: 
    requests: 
      storage: 100Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
        env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: creds
                key: username
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom: 
              secretKeyRef:
                name: creds
                key: password 
        volumeMounts: 
          - name: mongodb-storage
            mountPath: /data/db  
      volumes: 
        - name: mongodb-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: mongodb-pvc                
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Comment: the express server and application running in same namespace? `mongodb-service`?

Comment: better to post how the mongo db deployed?

Comment: all applications run on the default namespace